# I don't understand how parameter sweep is done in the Azure Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, epoch, azure-machine-learning-service

In azure ml if we select a train algorithm(for ex "Two Class Logistic Regression") we can then have a set of parameters to do a parameter sweep while training.But how can I know how they change values of parameters in the training?

Answer (score 3):

In Azure ML Studio, go to Experiments -> Samples and find "Model Parameter Optimization : Sweep parameters" experiment. This sample shows how parameter sweeping works. Basically:

1. In the algorithm module ("Two-Class Support Vector Machine"), set "Create trainer mode" to "Parameter Range" and specify the range of parameters you want to sweep over. This can be either min,max range, or a comma-separates list of values like 1,2,4,8.
2. In Tune Model Hyperparameters, specify the sweeping strategy "Entire Grid" (expensive),  "Random Sweep" (random points within min,max range) or "Random Grid" (random sampling of points from a grid).
3. The left output of Tune Model Hyperparameters should show a table of metrics for each combination of parameters that was swept over. The right output should contain the best model given the metric you selected.

Hope this helps,

Roope